# Create Table based on values of another table in Postgres

Tags: postgresql

I want to write a query to create table based on the values of column present in my second table.
For Example
My table having columns  with data

```
1 var1
2 var2
```

then I want to create new table with columns  where var1 and var2 are the values from my old table

Comment: Given that you cannot create a table *without* columns, your question is quite unclear.  Sample data and desired results would help convey what you are trying to do.

Comment: Is it clear sir or should i elaborate more